# What this T.11803 () mean in the Tracelog?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Here is my Tracelog, but I couldn't really find any documentation what this T.11803 () is for?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffe7abff700 (LWP 3441)]
0x00000000009c3a50 in T.11803 ()
#0  0x00000000009c3a50 in T.11803 ()
#1  0x00000000009e317d in Item::RemoveCategory() ()
#2  0x0000000000d14e08 in Item::HandleCategory(Application const*, unsigned item, bool) const ()
#3  0x0000000000d19e5c in Item::HandleEffect(Application*, unsigned item, bool) ()
#4  0x0000000000cf135a in Application::_HandleEffect(unsigned item, bool)
```

Comment: If the reason for the crash is a corrupted stack, you can't trust the call-stack. Otherwise it might be something temporary created by the compiler? Perhaps a lambda function? I don't know how GCC (I assume) names them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't really find any documentation what this T.11803 () is for?

You wouldn't.

Likely this is a local symbol, generated by your compiler (you didn't tell us *which* compiler you used to build your program).

You should be able to confirm this with `nm your_binary | grep 'T\.11803'`.

This could be a `C++11` lambda function (unlikely), or a part of your `Item::RemoveCategory()` function that the compiler decided to split out (perhaps because it is unlikely to be executed).

In any case, your first step should be to rebuild your code with `-g` flag, so you can see which file and line the crash happens on, and what variable values at crash point are.